# Программная установка выбранного элемента cxDBLookupCombobox

Tags: delphi, devexpress

1) Решаю такую задачу сейчас: пытаюсь добиться от компонента tcxDbLookupCombobox возможности программно выбрать пункт из списка. Если кто не знает, что за компонент, то скажу он входит в devexpress.

Такие банальные вещи, как:

```
cxDBLookupComboBox1.Text:=<значение из списка>;
cxDBLookupComboBox1.Properties.grid.DataController.Value[<Код записи>, 0];
```

не работают, как надо. Потому хотел бы знать, как можно программно установить, например, 3-ю запись из списка (Иванов Владимир Николаевич) не только визуально в поле Text, но и во внутреннем наборе данного компонента? Или список представляет собой "fio" и "id", и чтобы по какому-то событию (Клик кнопки) установить текущим значение не только в заголовке, но и в наборе данных то значение.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все доступные данные, которые связаны с текущей записью выбранной из списка являются read only, а значит менять их нельзя. Как решить эту проблему я пока не знаю), потому пишу здесь. Пока при первом событии onChange список устанавливает на первую запись из набора данных. Как на картинке, это будет "Петров Иван Васильевич". После того как пользователь уже самостоятельно выбирает значение, курсор текущей записи во внутреннем наборе данных тоже сменяется.

2) И второй вопрос, как заставить этот компонент распознавать нужную запись в случае если на вывод идет фамилия, например, а в popmenu там еще отображаются коды, имена, отчества людей. И получается такая странная ситуация, что событие OnChange, которое работает иначе, чем у стандартных Combobox, игнорирует смену однофамильцев. Если я стою на Иванове Иван, и выбираю Иванова Петра, то событие OnChange не понимает, что сменилось значение, а следовательно не меняет код возвращаемого от списка. Операция DISTINCT не годится для этого варианта, так как совокупности ФИО уникальны, но по раздельности в полях у нас может быть много Ивановых, Петровых. И на вывод выбранное значение подается только фамилия, а не полное ФИО.

Как решить эту проблему? В демо-примерах от разработчиков обнаружил такую же проблему, что у них не распознает оно как надо такие вещи.

С этими компонентами мало работал, и могу сказать у них принцип отличается от большинства стандартных компонентов. А если учесть, что просмотреть код этих компонентов тоже нельзя, так как разработчики сокрыли такую возможность, остается полагаться только на документацию и более опытных разработчиков с этими компонентами.

Comment: давно не работал с ним, но как помню решал с помощью Locate.

Answer (score 1):

У тебя контрол имеет в названии волшебные буквы DB. В свойствах этого контрола есть DataBinding, где прописывается DataSource и FieldName поля, к которому привязан данный контрол. Какое значение стоит в поле, то и отображается. Т.е., если надо отобразить (как в твоем примере "Иванов Владимир Николаевич", то надо связанному полю в датасете присвоить значение <3>.
Например, в связанном ListSource данная запись имеет ID=3. В DataSource прописан dsYourDataSet, поле DriverFIO.
в коде пишешь:

```
qYourDataSet.Edit;
qYourDataSet.FieldByName('DriverFIO').asInteger:=3;
qYourDataSet.Post;
```

Вуаля! Запись в комбо будет отображать "Иванов Владимир Николаевич"

Answer (score -1):

```
cxDBLookupComboBox1.EditValue:=<ИД записи>
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?